# Delete folder and all files/subdirectories

Tags: c++, file-io, delete-directory

How can I delete a folder with all it's files/subdirectories (recursive deletion) in C++?

Comment: Just a side node: There is a duplicate to this question, if you do not want to rely on boost, it is worth to have a look at the accepted answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2256974/1312382).

Answer (score 23):

Seriously:

```
system("rm -rf /path/to/directory")
```

Perhaps more what you're looking for, but unix specific:

```
/* Implement system( "rm -rf" ) */
    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Call unlink or rmdir on the path, as appropriate. */
int
rm(const char *path, const struct stat *s, int flag, struct FTW *f)
{
        int status;
        int (*rm_func)(const char *);
        (void)s;
        (void)f;
        rm_func = flag == FTW_DP ? rmdir : unlink;
        if( status = rm_func(path), status != 0 ){
                perror(path);
        } else if( getenv("VERBOSE") ){
                puts(path);
        }
        return status;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        (void)argc;
        while( *++argv ) {
                if( nftw(*argv, rm, OPEN_MAX, FTW_DEPTH) ){
                        perror(*argv);
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How portable is `system( "rm -rf /path/to/directory" )`? Will it work on any *nix OS? Clearly won't work in Windows.

Comment: It might be worth using `FTW_MOUNT|FTW_PHYS|FTW_DEPTH` instead of just `FTW_DEPTH` — that avoids disasters with symlinks and mounted file systems.  See [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)
for details.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `boost::remove_all` from [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Operations-functions).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ftw()`, `nftw()`, `readdir()`, `readdir_r()` to traverse a directory and delete files recursively.
But since neither `ftw()`, `nftw()`, `readdir()` is thread-safe, I'll recommend `readdir_r()` instead if your program runs in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17 the prefered answer to this would be to use

```
std::filesystem::remove_all(const std::filesystem::path& folder)
```

which deletes the content of the folder recursively and then finally deletes the folder, according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove).

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ provides no means of doing this - you will have to use operating system specific code or a cross-platform library such as Boost.