# Matrix multiplication using array generating erronous results

Tags: c, arrays, matrix-multiplication

The following code multiplies two matrices of different orders and returns results i.e **mat1 (6x3) * mat2 (3x6)** and returns 6x6 matrix in **dest**

The problem is the result doesn't match with the calculated value. Additionally, if you observe the results  **mat2** is changing its contents.

> PS: iterals: 3, 0, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 20.000000
>   dest[3][0] = 0.000000
>
> The original content of mat2[1][0] was zero.

**OUTPUT:**

```
iterals: 0, 0, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][0] = 1.000000   dest[0][0] = 10.000000
iterals: 0, 0, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 0.000000   dest[0][0] = 10.000000
iterals: 0, 0, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[0][0] = 10.000000
iterals: 0, 1, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[0][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 1, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[0][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 1, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[0][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 2, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[0][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 2, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][2] = 1.000000   dest[0][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 2, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[0][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 3, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[0][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 3, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[0][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 3, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[0][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 4, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[0][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 4, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[0][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 4, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][4] = 1.000000   dest[0][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 5, 0    mat1[0][0] = 10.000000  mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[0][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 5, 1    mat1[0][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[0][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 0, 5, 2    mat1[0][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[0][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 0, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][0] = 1.000000   dest[1][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 0, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 0.000000   dest[1][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 0, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[1][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 1, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[1][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 1, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[1][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 1, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[1][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 2, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[1][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 2, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][2] = 1.000000   dest[1][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 2, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[1][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 3, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[1][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 3, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[1][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 3, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[1][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 4, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[1][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 4, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[1][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 4, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][4] = 1.000000   dest[1][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 5, 0    mat1[1][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[1][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 5, 1    mat1[1][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[1][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 1, 5, 2    mat1[1][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[1][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 0, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][0] = 0.000000   dest[2][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 0, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][0] = 0.000000   dest[2][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 0, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[2][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 1, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[2][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 1, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[2][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 1, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[2][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 2, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[2][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 2, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][2] = 1.000000   dest[2][2] = 20.000000
iterals: 2, 2, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[2][2] = 20.000000
iterals: 2, 3, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[2][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 3, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[2][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 3, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[2][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 4, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[2][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 4, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[2][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 4, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][4] = 1.000000   dest[2][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 5, 0    mat1[2][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[2][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 5, 1    mat1[2][1] = 20.000000  mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[2][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 2, 5, 2    mat1[2][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[2][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 0, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][0] = 0.000000   dest[3][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 0, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 20.000000  dest[3][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 0, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[3][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 1, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[3][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 1, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[3][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 1, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[3][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 2, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[3][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 2, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][2] = 0.000000   dest[3][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 2, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[3][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 3, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[3][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 3, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[3][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 3, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[3][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 4, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[3][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 4, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[3][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 4, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][4] = 1.000000   dest[3][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 5, 0    mat1[3][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[3][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 5, 1    mat1[3][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[3][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 3, 5, 2    mat1[3][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[3][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 0, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][0] = 0.000000   dest[4][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 0, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 20.000000  dest[4][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 0, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[4][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 1, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[4][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 1, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[4][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 1, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[4][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 2, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[4][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 2, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][2] = 0.000000   dest[4][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 2, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[4][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 3, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[4][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 3, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[4][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 3, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[4][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 4, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[4][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 4, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[4][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 4, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][4] = 0.000000   dest[4][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 5, 0    mat1[4][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[4][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 5, 1    mat1[4][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[4][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 4, 5, 2    mat1[4][2] = 30.000000  mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[4][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 0, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][0] = 0.000000   dest[5][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 0, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][0] = 20.000000  dest[5][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 0, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][0] = 0.000000   dest[5][0] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 1, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][1] = 0.000000   dest[5][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 1, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][1] = 0.000000   dest[5][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 1, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][1] = 0.000000   dest[5][1] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 2, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][2] = 0.000000   dest[5][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 2, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][2] = 0.000000   dest[5][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 2, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][2] = 0.000000   dest[5][2] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 3, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][3] = 0.000000   dest[5][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 3, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][3] = 0.000000   dest[5][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 3, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][3] = 0.000000   dest[5][3] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 4, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][4] = 0.000000   dest[5][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 4, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][4] = 0.000000   dest[5][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 4, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][4] = 0.000000   dest[5][4] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 5, 0    mat1[5][0] = 0.000000   mat2[0][5] = 0.000000   dest[5][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 5, 1    mat1[5][1] = 0.000000   mat2[1][5] = 0.000000   dest[5][5] = 0.000000
iterals: 5, 5, 2    mat1[5][2] = 0.000000   mat2[2][5] = 0.000000   dest[5][5] = 0.000000
```

Here is the **source code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void prod(float mat1[][6], float mat2[][6], float dest[][6], int m1, int n1, int n2) {
     printf("orders: %d, %d, %d\n", m1, n1, n2);
     int i, j, k; // kmax = n1, jmax = n2, imax = m1
     for (i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
             dest[i][j] = 0;
             for (k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                 dest[i][j] += mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
                 printf("iterals: %d, %d, %d\t", i, j, k);
                 printf("mat1[%d][%d] = %f\t", i, k, mat1[i][k]);
                 printf("mat2[%d][%d] = %f\t", k, j, mat2[k][j]);
                 printf("dest[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j, dest[i][j]);
             }
         }
     }
 }


void main() {
    float res[][6] = { 0 };

    float G[][6] =  { {10,  0,  0},
                      { 0,  0,  0},
                      { 0, 20,  0},
                      { 0,  0,  0},
                      { 0,  0, 30},
                      { 0,  0,  0} };

    float H[][6] =  { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0} };

    prod(G, H, res, 6, 3, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float res[][6] = { 0 };` is a `float res[1][6];` and not a `float res[6][6];` as you would need. If you do not have a full initializer list, you need to write out all dimensions.

Also `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Your initializer list of `G` also does not fit the `float G[][6]`, it should be a `float G[][3]`.

Here is the full code: https://ideone.com/2hz45m

Comment: @suvojit_007 this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18446686/3684343 . in short: under normal conditions yes.

Comment: @mch Why is **mat2[1][0]** element value is changing to 20.00?

Comment: Your `res` array was too small, so you were writing out of bounds and overwrote something else. This invokes undefined behaviour and so weird results can occur. Is the result here https://ideone.com/2hz45m as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `float res[][6] = { 0 };` is too small, which others [@mch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942799/2410359), [@Rishikesh Raje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942909/2410359) have said, other problems exists.

---

Consider `mat1[][6], mat2[][6], dest[][6]` as `mat1[a][b], mat2[b][c], dest[a][c]` for clearer and more flexible code.

In C99 and optionally in C11, a parameter may be a [variable length array - VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99), which simplifies coding.
See [Passing a multidimensional variable length array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14548753/2410359)

```
void prod(int a, int b, int c, float mat1[a][b], float mat2[b][c], float dest[a][c]) {
  printf("orders: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
  for (int ai = 0; ai < a; ai++) {
    for (int ci = 0; ci < c; ci++) {
      float sum = 0.0;
      for (int bi = 0; bi < b; bi++) {
        sum += mat1[ai][bi] * mat2[bi][ci];
        printf("iterals: %d, %d, %d\t", ai, ci, bi);
        printf("mat1[%d][%d] = %2g\t", ai, bi, mat1[ai][bi]);
        printf("mat2[%d][%d] = %2g\t", bi, ci, mat2[bi][ai]);
        printf("dest[%d][%d] = %2g\n", ai, ci, sum);
      }
      dest[ai][ci] = sum;
    }
  }
}

#define A 6
#define B 3
#define C 6

int main(void) {
  float g[A][B] = { //
      {10, 0, 0}, //
      {0, 0, 0}, //
      {0, 20, 0}, //
      {0, 0, 0}, //
      {0, 0, 30}, //
      {0, 0, 0}};
  float h[B][C] = { // Note dimension change
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, //
      {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, //
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
  float res[A][C]; // Note dimension change

  prod(A, B, C, g, h, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `G` matrix does not have 6 columns. It has 3 columns and should be defined as below

   ```
   float G[][3]
   ```
2. The result matrix needs a size.

   ```
    float res[6][6] = { 0 };
   ```
3. You should define main as `int main(void)`
4. The function definition shall also change as below.

   ```
   void prod(float mat1[][3], float mat2[][6], float dest[][6], int m1, int n1, int n2) {
   ```