# why these two programs giving different outputs?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, operating-system

I tried the following programs on Linux system using `gcc` compiler, both are giving different outputs. Can anyone explain the results?

**Program 1**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i=10;

int add(){
  printf("hai");
  i=i+1;
}

void main(){
  int k;
  k=add();
  printf("%d",k);
}
```

**Program 2**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add(){
      int i=10;
      printf("hai");
      i=i+1;
}

void main(){
     int k;
     k=add();

     printf("%d",k);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`add` is supposed to return an `int` but you have no `return` statement at the end of the function so you are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and so we can not reason about the results. The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12* says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Probably not directly related but still important is that `main` should return and `int` not `void`, the C99 draft standard in section `5.1.2.2.1` *Program startup* paragraph *1* says:

```
It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

  int main(void) { /* ... */ }

or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: good to know you have given some answer, but what  i heard is like printf is returning some value so it will be stored in register, and this can taken by the calling function as we see in program2. do u know anything about this ?  @shafik

Comment: @user2773010: That's not defined behavior, don't count on it.

Comment: @user2773010 When you are dealing with undefined behavior you can sometimes make good guesses about what will happen but it will be compiler, platform etc.. dependent and it will only be a guess. [Deep C and C++](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) is a good intro but please only do this type of stuff to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior, the function `add` is supposed to returned `int` but has no `return` statement to actually return a value. From the code, I'm guessing what you want is:

```
int i = 10;
int add(){
  printf("hai");
  i=i+1;
  return i;  //here
}
```

The other one is similar, try it and see the result.

Another undefined behavior is `void main`, as many posts in SO have already stated, you should always use `int main(void)`.  Look ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)*** for a good discussion on this.

Answer (score 1):

In Both programs you did not return any thing from `add()` function. And `k` did not initialized before .

return value from `add()` is any unexpected value.

either try to print `i` value or else add `return` statement in function `add()`

**try 1**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void add();
int i=10;
void add(){
  i=i+1;
}
void main(){
add(); 
printf("%d",i); 
//i is global variable so changes made in function will gets effectes here and prints 11
}
```

**try 2**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add();
int i=10;
int add(){
  return i+1; //return i+1 
}
void main(){
int k;
k=add();
printf("%d",k); //here k value will modify but i value does not. print i value also
}
```

**try 3**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void add();
void add(){
  int i=10; //i is local to add() function.
  i=i+1;     
}
void main(){
int i=10;
add();
printf("%d",i); //now i value wont change because i is local to main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'add' function does not return any value. What got returned may be a garbage value, which may be different for the two programs or even 2 invocations of the same program.