# Unclear about return value of a void function in C

Tags: c, gcc

The following C program has a function `test()`, which despite having no return statement, returns either:

1. The number of characters in the format of `printf()`
2. The ASCII value of the character, if a single character is present in the format of `printf()`
3. Value of one of its arguments for `printf("")`.

How can a function without a `return` statement return a value and why the variability in results?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(int, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("\n%d\n", argc);
    if (argc > 1)
    {
            printf("\n%d\n", test(atoi(*++argv), 2));
            printf("\n%d\n", test(2, atoi(*argv)));
    }

    return 0;
}

int test(int a, int b)
{
    printf("0");
}
```

---

Comment: Undefined Behaviour

Comment: it might not have an explicit return value but you are returning a value! The compiler should have issued a warning to you that the return value is not defined.

Comment: strange, I was expecting nasal demons

Comment: Using the return value [of a function that does not have a return statement is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767052/why-these-two-programes-giving-different-outputs).

Comment: Why does that even compile? Use compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: @MagnusHoff, this: "How can a function without a return statement return a value and why the variability in results?", sorry wasn't able to frame the question clearly, but someone edited that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result in this situation is based on whats on top of the stack when test() is returned.  The behaviour is undefined.

You should compile your code with warnings enabled:

## gcc main.c -Wall

Also, altering your argv pointer is a bit dirty.  De-referencing argv directly communicates your intentions in a clear way:

```
printf("\n%d\n", test(atoi(*++argv), 2));
printf("\n%d\n", test(2, atoi(*argv)));
```

Should be:

```
printf("\n%d\n", test( atoi(argv[1]), 2) );
printf("\n%d\n", test( 2, atoi(argv[1]) ) );
```

Comment: Who says that whatever ABI the OP uses puts return values on the stack?

Comment: Thanks @Luke Dupin, I tried with the -Wall param, it returned this: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]. Also, thanks for the programming tip. And because of all the reasons in all the answers, the output would be undefined I guess. Well, learnt something new then...

Comment: @Luke Dupin, I believe the argv[2] in the line 2 should be argv[1].

Answer (score 0):

The way values are returned from a function is different in different architectures.  In most of them, it is the value of some CPU register.  If you don't specifically use `return`, the content of that register is what the compiler "sees" as the return value of the function.  Sometimes, it is the return value of the last function called, but sometimes it can be other things.  The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at [this slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) page 22

Values are tossed around in registers.. and that makes this behaviour undefined.