# Median calculation from float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, median

I have a program which reads floating point numbers from a .txt file and puts them into an array but I have a problem with calculating median. Everything is working perfectly except from this. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  float fa = *(float*) a;
  float fb = *(float*) b;
  return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}



//median calculations//
float median1(float[],int); 
float median1(float array[],int n) 
{  
qsort(array, n, sizeof(float), compare);

if(n%2==0)  
    return (array[n/2]+array[n/2-1])/2;  
else  
    return array[n/2];  
}



float x,l=~(257<<23),a,s,t,median;
main(int n,char**f)

{
char fname[20];
int i;
a=-l;

printf("Please type the file name with an extension (.txt)\n");
scanf("%s", fname);


f=fopen(fname,"r");
for(n=0;fscanf(f,"%f",&x)>0;n++,s+=x,x<l?l=x:0,x>a?a=x:0,t+=x*x);

float array[n];

fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);

for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
        {
            fscanf (f, "%f", &(array[n]));
        }

median=median1(array,n);  

printf("Sample size = %d\n", n);
printf("Minimum = %f\n", l);
printf("Maximum = %f\n", a);
printf("Mean = %f\n", s/n);
printf("Median = %f\n",median);
printf("Standard deviation = %f\n", sqrtf(t/n));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what's not working. Is it giving the wrong value? Try to step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Nabla what do you mean twice?

Comment: Why would you have a collection of global variables like `x`, `l`, etc? Make them local.  I'm puzzled about the initializer for `l` — quite honestly, I've no idea what it's supposed to do with bit operations on an integer assigned to a `float`.  You'd also lose any marks I was giving out for the line `for(n=0;fscanf(f,"%f",&x)>0;n++,s+=x,x<l?l=x:0,x>a?a=x:0,t+=x*x);`. That is diabolical — ridiculous — code.

Comment: This is the highest possible float value.

Comment: @xLokos The highest possible float value is `FLT_MAX` from `<float.h>`.

Comment: But it's still high enough I think? It's about 011111110111111111111111111111111111 in binary code.

Comment: @xLokos It's high enough so long as no one tries to input something higher.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The program in this question is a (barely) indented version of a humorous answer given to the OP's previous question. The  intention behind `~(257<<23)` is clearly to create the bit pattern for FLT_MAX, except that 1) conversion from `float` to `int` does not work this way 2) `257 << 23` is undefined behavior on typical 32-bit platforms.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ahah — much is explained!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fscanf (f, "%f", &(array[n]));
```

should be

```
fscanf (f, "%f", &(array[i]));
```

You are only writing to one array element and that one is out-of-bound.

Even if this wouldn't result in undefined behavior, you would still work with garbage values later on.

See @JonathanLeffler's comment for some further remarks on your code.

Comment: The first read counts how many values there are. This is used to allocate the VLA `float array[n];` of the correct size.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah ok, I was confused because `n` is for some reason the first parameter to `main`.

Comment: You're excused for being confused; I hadn't even noticed that.  Gruesome doesn't really begin to describe some of the coding feats in here.  Notice that `f` is the other argument to `main(int n, char **f)`, but is also used as a `FILE *` in `f = fopen(fname, "r");` — there's a serious case of not paying attention to compiler warnings here!

Comment: Yup, what he said. I need to create an array to calculate median, and I didn't want to use dynamic one.

Comment: Reading the file twice is probably more costly than using dynamic memory allocation.  You'd have to measure to be sure, and if the file is small enough (say under 1 KiB), then you probably won't be able to detect the difference.

Comment: If it's not an error I don't even look at it ;) Still after changing that line it returns value wchich isn't even in the txt file

Comment: @xLokos: You need to learn to write code so that it is squeaky clean with no warnings even with the warning levels turned way up.  If you use `gcc`, the bare minimum should be `-Wall`. I don't write code that doesn't compile clean with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -O3 -g -std=c11` as my default warnings.  I sometimes add some others; very occasionally I relax the prototype warnings if it is someone else's code.

Comment: So what should I change the `main` arguments to?

Comment: @xLokos You don't use them, so either remove them (`int main(void)`) or give them the usual names `argc` and `argv`. Also they are typically not written to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c

Comment: Ok, now when I implemented all the corrections you suggested I get no warnings when compiling anymore. However the numbers returned by the program are different from those in txt file. For example my min in txt is -321.654 and the program shows Minimum =  -321.653992, max is 12654986.5684523 and it shows 12654987.000000. Any idea why? Median is still a random number not present in the file at all.

Comment: @xLokos Are you talking about the answer of @JonathanLeffler? If so please post your comment under his answer. I do not claim that the error I found is the only one. Your code is hard to read.

Comment: You only get about six sigfigs from a float, so -321.653992 is most likely the closest representable value to -321.654.

Comment: Did you remember to initialize `s` and `t` to zero before you start incrementing them?  If not, you start with garbage and add good numbers to it, but GIGO — garbage in, garbage out.  You could print the values as you go, of course, as a simple way of debugging — what was the value just read, and what are the control variables (`s`, `t`, `a`, `l`, `n`) now set to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaned up version of your code…but select [Nabla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072164/nabla)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358844/15168).

It compiles cleanly with:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror med.c -o med
```

It shows that you were not dreadfully far off.  I have not fixed the initializer for `l`.  I did ensure that `s` and `t` are both zeroed before you start accumulating values in them.  The code does not check that `fscanf()` works on the second pass.  I've not fixed it to read from standard input or to take the file name from its arguments, either of which would make it a lot more usable.

Given input data:

```
1.2
3.5
2.9
4.6
```

it produces the output:

```
Sample size = 4
Minimum = 1.200000
Maximum = 4.600000
Mean = 3.050000
Median = 3.200000
Standard deviation = 3.288617
```

#### Semi-fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b);

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    float fa = *(float *) a;
    float fb = *(float *) b;
    return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}

// median calculations//
float median1(float[], int);

float median1(float array[], int n)
{
    qsort(array, n, sizeof(float), compare);

    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return (array[n / 2] + array[n / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    else
        return array[n / 2];
}

int main(void)
{
    float x;
    float l = ~(257 << 23);
    float a;
    float s = 0.0;
    float t = 0.0;
    float median;
    int n;
    FILE *f;
    char fname[20];
    int i;
    a = -l;

    printf("Please type the file name with an extension (.txt)\n");
    scanf("%s", fname);


    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (f == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", fname);
        return 1;
    }

    for (n = 0; fscanf(f, "%f", &x) > 0; n++)
    {
        s += x;
        if (x<l) l = x;
        if (x>a) a = x;
        t += x * x;
    }

    float array[n];

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%f", &(array[i]));
    }

    fclose(f);

    median = median1(array, n);

    printf("Sample size = %d\n", n);
    printf("Minimum = %f\n", l);
    printf("Maximum = %f\n", a);
    printf("Mean = %f\n", s / n);
    printf("Median = %f\n", median);
    printf("Standard deviation = %f\n", sqrtf(t / n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't say it doesn't look much neater. But still even with this code and input `123.456 999.999 564.312 -654.321 7894.32` it produces output `Sample size = 5
Minimum = -654.320984
Maximum = 7894.319824
Mean = 1785.553101
Median = 564.312012
Standard deviation = 3580.003174
`

Comment: That's what I get too from your data: `Sample size = 5
Minimum = -654.320984
Maximum = 7894.319824
Mean = 1785.553101
Median = 564.312012
Standard deviation = 3580.003174`.  It's reasonable given the inputs. Trying to get 10 significant digits from a value that can only hold 6-7 is an exercise in futility, but the default precision for `%f` is 6 decimal places, so that's what gets printed.

Comment: So do you think this whole code will be accepted by my tutor?

Comment: I just checked with my GCC and the stdev is slightly different from this in output. My Casio shows `sample stdev = 3469.18976`

Comment: Btw thatnks for your help and time, I appreciate it.

Comment: I think the problem with the standard deviation is that you're using ∑x²/n instead of √(∑(nx²-µ²)/(n(n-1))).  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) and [MathsIsFun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html) for more information.

Comment: Why n(n-1)? should it look like t += (x-(s/n))²  and return value of stdev = t/n in my case?

Comment: Nvm, I've done it another way and it works now. Thank you again ;)