# No output for cout?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, division, cout

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

int doIt(int a){
    a=a/1000;
    return a;
}

void main(){
    int myfav= 23412;
    cout<<"test: "+doIt(myfav);
    cin.get();
}
```

just wondering why i am not getting a print out for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be `int main`. It shouldn't compile as is, which would explain no output.

Comment: @chris Most compilers will take `void main` to mean `int main` always returning 0. There might even be something in a spec somewhere about that interpretation.

Comment: @ssube, Neither GCC, nor Clang takes it, and I presume MSVC as well (though maybe only newer versions if it compiles for the OP). And I'm sure it's not allowed. The standard explicitly says it must return `int`. The only compiler I know of that I'm sure accepts that is TurboC++.

Comment: @chris VS will allow it (and assume a `return 0` always).  I believe VS2013 gives a warning about it, but VS2010 does not.  That said, it is non-standard.

Comment: @chris It looks like, judging from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c), that it's an old C-ism and may actually be legal. I've certainly done that before on accident, although the specifics of how and when escape me.

Comment: @ssube, Yes, the wording changed from C to C++.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Presumably, thinking that it would convert the integer to a string and concatenate it, as other languages do. That's the error, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++ streams, you should `cout << "test: " << doIt(myfav)`, rather than trying to `+` them together. I'm not sure off the top of my head whether `<<` or `+` takes precedence, but regardless of whether you're adding to a stream or a string literal, that's not going to work very well.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking in java while coding in c++, probably should learn one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

`void main()` is not a valid signature for your `main` function (though, VS will recognize it, it is not standard-compliant).  It should be `int main()`.

You cannot insert an integer into to a string using `+`.  You need to use the extraction operator of `std::ostream`:  `operator<<`.  What you have will result in pointer arithmetic (adding the result from `doIt` to the address of your `const char*`, which is undefined behavior).

`std::cout` is a buffered output stream.  Since you do not flush your buffer, there is a chance that the program ends before you are able to see the output (prior to the console closing).  Change your output line to one of the following:

```
std::cout << "test:  " << doIt(myFav) << std::endl; // flush the buffer with a newline
```

or

```
std::cout << "test:  " << doIt(myFav) << std::flush; // flush the buffer
```

All in all, what you have will compile, but will not do what you want it to, at all.

Comment: The system *should* flush the buffers when the program ends, as long as it terminates normally.

Comment: Indeed, `std::cout`'s destructor calls `flush`.

Comment: @ssube Given that his current code will not even compile, that is the least of his worries.  IIRC, the version of the standard library that shipped with VS2010 did not flush the buffer in the destructor for `std::ostream`.

Comment: @ZacHowland, Eww, that's not nice. Although I do wonder what doesn't compile. If it's the addition, that actually will (and invoke UB here).

Comment: Additionally, since `flush` is synced with `std::cin`, it could be flushed as the program is exiting ... meaning it is printed, but the console closes before he can see it.

Comment: @chris - Actually, you are correct ... it would do pointer arithmetic.  I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

There are few this i would like to point out. First return type of main function `void main()` it should  be `int main()`.

Don't use `using namespace std;` for more detail visit [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Finally problem in your code you cannot insert an integer into to a string using +, you will have to extraction operator i.e. `<<` again.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <math.h>

//using namespace std;

int doIt(int a)
{
    a=a/1000;
    return a;
 }
int main()
{
    int myfav= 23412;
    std::cout<<"test: "<<doIt(myfav)<<"\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Without `using namespace std;`, what you have will not compile (unless you prepend `std::` in front of `cout` and `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

This expression `"test: "+doIt(myfav)` in statement

```
cout<<"test: "+doIt(myfav);
```

means that you add some integral value to the pointer that points to the first character of string literal "test: ".  And as the result the statement outputs obtained pointer value.

Your could use operator + if you would convert the integral value returned by the function to an object of type std::string. For example

```
cout<<"test: "+ to_string( doIt(myfav) );
```

To do this you need include header `<string>`
Take into account that function main shall have return type `int` in C/C++. And it is better to use header `<cmath>` instead of heder

Resuming all what I said I will show how the program can look

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

inline int doIt( int a ) { return a / 1000; }


int main()
{
    int myfav = 23412;

    std::cout << "test: " + std::to_string( doIt( myfav ) ) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: There isn't really a need to use `std::to_string` here as `std::ostream` has an overloaded `operator<<` for `int`.

Comment: @Zac Howland I showed how the statement could be written with operator + if he want to use it the same way as it is used in C#

Comment: @Zac Howland Also it is important to demonstrate when and where the operator + is overload that is to demonstrate the difference between "test: " + integer and "test: " + std::string.

Comment: I get that, but since `to_string` is going to call the `operator<<` overload anyway, it is a little silly to use it in this case.