# allocate memory to a string to write more data

Tags: c, malloc

I want to allocate memory in an existing and still want to save the stored data inside of that string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
char *str1= "hello";
char *str2= "Abhimanyu";

char *str = malloc( strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) +1 );

strcpy(str,str1);
strcat(str,str2);
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```

what i want is that i allocate some using malloc in the existing `str1` and not using `str` is it possible?

Comment: does it need to be in the same place or would something like `realloc` work?

Comment: It's not 1975 anymore; activate your compiler warnings and write proper C.

Comment: `str1` points to unmodifiable memory, so you can't concatenate to it. I don't see a good reason to use `realloc` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach that I see is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HELLO "hello"

int main( void )
{
   char *str2 = "Abhimanyu";
   char *str1 = malloc( sizeof( HELLO ) );

   strcpy( str1, HELLO );

   str1 = realloc( str1, strlen( str1 ) + strlen( str2 ) +1 );
   strcat( str1, str2 );

   printf( "%s\n", str1 );

   free( str1 );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to check if `malloc`/`realloc` failed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow should it be like this ////////  str1 = (char *) relloc(str1 , new_size) ?

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't There is no necessity to specify the casting in C thogh for the documentation purpose it is useful to specify it.

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't-1 you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` in C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

> what i want is that i allocate some using malloc in the existing str1 and not using str is it possible?

You can certainly point `str1` to some other memory if you no longer need it to point to the string literal.
Just assign the new value.
The function for reallocating is [`realloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

Some facts you might need:

- A string literal may not be changed, even though it has type `char[]` it is actually constant.
  It is allocated statically, so has nothing to do with `malloc`and such.
  All constant literals, including string literals, can potentially share storage.
- There's a POSIX function for duplicating a string (memory internally allocated with `malloc`): [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)
- You can `realloc` memory allocated with compatible functions on the heap. That includes: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` (`strdup`). Don't forget `free`.
- If you reallocate memory, unless the reallocation fails (returns `NULL`), you may not use the old pointer any longer. All data was copied from the old to the new memory block, up to the minimum of old and new length. The rest is uninitialized.

Aside: Be aware that `main` nearly always has a return type of `int`, and implicit return types are ancient legacy.
If you use a decent compiler, asking for all warnings `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and selecting a modern standard (C99 or C11) will help you.

Comment: Regarding _that main always has a return type of int_  Caution when using _always_ or _never_.    The C99 standard does allow for other implementation-defined signatures, and you can use these if you've read the manual for your compiler and it says you can.

    ***(5.1.2.2.1) It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner***   ( ***[from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356660/645128)*** )

Comment: I am only a little disappointed that you are not offering an alternative point of view.  I'm not really up for a good strong debate on the topic, as I am not even pedantic about that rule, I just notice _always_ and _never_ rarely apply. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) to increase the memory block pointed to by a pointer but the realloc implementation may end up moving your data to a different location in memory and changing the pointer's address so you should always double check your pointer. This can happen if the requested new size is larger than what's available.

If there's a really good reason why you need to be able to dynamically resize a memory block pointed to by a pointer then you probably need to think about building your own memory allocator or buffer pool and take ownership of managing the memory in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `realloc` to *try* to resize *a previous allocation*. It does *not* work on arbitrary pointers, such as your `str1 = "hello"`† – you need to allocate the initial area with, e.g., `malloc`. It may also end up allocating a new area at a different address (and copying the contents of the old area there), i.e., you must update *all* pointers that refer to the old area to point to the new area returned by `realloc`.

If these constraints are not acceptable, you are out of luck and need to design your program in some other way (e.g., set a maximum length and reserve that much space to begin with, then just use as much as you need).

† Also note that string literals, such as `"hello"`, are not modifiable to begin with. The typical way around this is to use an array instead, e.g., `char str1[] = "hello"`, but that can't be resized either. (But you could specify a larger size for it than needed for its initial contents if you know you will be storing a longer string there later.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking whether you can take this declaration:

```
char * str1 = "hello";
```

and somehow cause there to be some extra space available pointed to by `str1`.

The answer is **don't do this!**  Notice that `str1` is a local (stack) variable. It probably points to some literal pool, but it may point to more space allocated on the stack.

So doing this sort of thing

```
char * str1 = hello;
...
str1 = realloc (str1, 100);
```

may give rise to dom!  (a UNIX sixth edition joke appropriate to the OP's style of coding).

Comment: It has to point to something with static storage duration (up to the as-if rule, of course); e.g. if this function returned `str1` then the pointer has to remain valid.