# Why is a divide by error coming?

Tags: c++, divide

A divide by zero error is being shown in the following code..
I am using dosbox 0.74 compiler

```
int chkpm(int,int);
void main()
{
    int num,i,count=-1;

    cout<<"Enter a number\n";
    cin>>num;
    for(i=0;i<=num/2;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {       //test
            `enter code here`cout<<"num%i=0";

     count=chkpm(num,i);
        }
        if(count>0)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ^ "<<count;
        }
    }
    cout<<"bye test \n";
    getch();
}
int chkpm(int num,int i)
{
    int j,flag=0; //flag will be true if i is not prime factor
    int count=0;        //to calculate power of prime factor
    for(j=0;j<=i/2;j++)  //to check for prime
    {
        if(i%j==0)  //check for divisibility
        {
            flag=1; //that means i is not prime
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)   //if factor i is prime,flag is 0
    {
        while(num%i==0) //keep dividing prime factor by num
        {       count++;  //to count power
            num=num/i;
        }
        return count;
    }
    else return -1;        //when flag=1, i.e. factor not prime
}
```

Error is showing when I re-execute the code, not at compile time
I've tried all kinds of inputs ranging from zero to positive numbers.........

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your problem lies with performing modulo of 0. `num%i` when `i==0` will yield the error. What is the remainder when dividing by zero? Divide by zero error!

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be using int main() instead of void.

Comment: He's right..It was 0%0 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<=num/2;i++)
{
    if(num%i==0)
    ...
}
```

Here `i` will start from value 0. `%` means modulo, which actually implies that a division will take place, thus you divide by zero in the if condition.

Inside your function you have a similar logical error:

```
for(j=0;j<=i/2;j++)  //to check for prime
{
    if(i%j==0)
    ...
}
```

If you don't fix `main()`, then the function will have `i` equal to zero which will cause more damage.

---

You use `void main()`, instead of the typical `int main()`. You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c) relevant question. Then a `return 0` before you exit `main()` should be added.

Comment: Done. i should start from 2 then

Comment: @AbhishekWadhawan make sure you fix the similar logical errors inside your function too! If you are OK with the answer accept it so that the question appears as answered in the question feed.