# Program to accept an array of n elements and count number of palindromes

Tags: arrays

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 int x,d,a[10],i,sum=0,count=0,n;
 cout<<"Enter no of numbers:";
 cin>>n;
 for(i=0;i<n;++i)
 {
    cout<<"Enter number"<<i+1<<":";
    cin>>a[i];
 }
 for(i=0;i<n;++i)
 { 
   x=a[i];
   while(x!=0)
   { 
      d=x%10;
      sum=sum*10+d;
      x=x/10;
   }
   if(sum==a[i])
       count++;
 }
 cout<<"No of palidromes:"<<count;   
 }
```

I entered 121,134 and 1331 but the output was always 1. In fact I tried more numbers and still got only 1. Please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sum = 0;` after your `x=a[i];`

Comment: @SMcCK You also could crash if n > 10. One last thing - void main, not recommended (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)

Comment: @ClsForCookies We just started with c++. Our teacher told us to keep the standard array length as 10 for all programs.

Comment: @SMcCK No problem, but if so you should check your input so n <= 9

Comment: @ClsForCookies Yes,I'll do that from now on.