# C4473 warning for structure assignment

Tags: c++, structure, scanf

I am currently working on an assignment and was curious what this warning is when compiling and how to remedy it. It will build but when I debug it will get an error screen. Below is the warning that comes up.

> 1>c:\users\cesteves\documents\c
>   programming\inventory\inventory\inventory.cpp(48): warning C4473:
>   'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
>
> note: placeholders and their parameters expect 2 variadic arguments,
>   but 1 were provided
>
> note: the missing variadic argument 2 is required by format string
>   '%s'   note: this argument is used as a buffer size

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    struct date {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };

    struct details {
        char name[20];
        int price;
        int code;
        int qty;
        struct date mfg;
    };

    struct details item[50];
    int n, i;

    printf("Enter number of items:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Item name: \n");
        scanf_s("%s", item[i].name);
        printf("Item code: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &item[i].code);
        printf("Quantity: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &item[i].qty);
        printf("price: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &item[i].price);
        printf("Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy): \n");
        scanf_s("%d-%d-%d", &item[i].mfg.day, &item[i].mfg.month, &item[i].mfg.year);    
    }

    printf("             *****  INVENTORY ***** \n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------- - \n");
    printf("S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE| MFG.DATE \n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------- - \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d%d / %d / %d \n", i + 1, item[i].name, item[i].code, item[i].qty,item[i].price, item[i].mfg.day, item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------- - \n");
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s` is safe scanf. Requires buffer size. `scanf_s("%s", item[i].name, 20); `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should provide a size of the buffer. For example, if you reading only one char, it should be like this:

```
char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

Please read the [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)!

Also, `structs` are nice to be placed before `main()`. I always have my [example](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/) in mind, on the basic usage of `structs`.

The prototype of main should be `int main(void)` in your case. Check this: [int main() vs void main() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)

---

In your code, change this:

```
scanf_s("%s", item[i].name);
```

to this:

```
scanf_s("%s", item[i].name, 20);
```

because of this:

```
struct details {
  char name[20];
  ..
```

Do the same for the rest..

Comment: A downvote for what please? If there is something wrong, tell me to update for the future users...

Comment: I appreciate the help and corrected the placement of the structure as well

Comment: @Chris I updated with an example for structs. Glad it helped, +1 for taking time to edit your post.

Comment: I downvoted. I felt the 'RTFM' comment was a bit unprofessional, you could have quoted the relevant section of the docs at that link. Your comment _Also, structs should be before main(). I always have my example in mind._ should have some sort of explanation. Are local structs allowed per the standard or not? A link(and a quote would be nice).  Is there a stylistic guideline that says you shouldn't etc?(A link to such info would be appropriate). As far as I know local structs are supported with C99, but not C89.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks for commenting. I agree on RTFM, I will remove it. As for the structs, I will update too. If you have any other problem with that please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
 scanf_s("%s", item[i].name);
```

`scanf_s` require's size as 3rd argument with specifiers `%s`, `%c` and `%[` .

You need to write like this -

```
 scanf_s("%s", item[i].name,20);
```

Similar , for taking input a single character pass `1` as size .

Comment: Hi, nice answer, +1. In fact it is really similar to mine's, but I have a downvote so I might have an error. Can you see any please?

Comment: @gsamaras I can't see any . Well , all could say it happen on SO ,its a part :-)

Comment: Maybe that's the case! @Chris don't forget to accept an answer you like!