# what does void main return to os when finished executing?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

We know `int main()` returns 0 to OS when it terminates  without error 
and non-zero in case of failure.
But how will the OS identify normal(without error) or abnormal(error) termination in case of `void main()`.

Comment: Such a program is a non-conforming C program. Anything can happen if a compiler accepts such a `main` function.

Comment: It won't. And therefore it is better to stick to that convention if you implement OS related functionalities.

Comment: @RSahu however it is implementation-defined if the compiler accepts `void main`, so such a compiler would have documented behaviour

Comment: @RSahu See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356660/1791872)