# 111-D Statement is unreachable on Return 0

Tags: c, stm32, keil

```
int main(void) {

    TIM4_Init();
    setSysTick();

    while (1) {
        TIM4->CCR1 = 600;       // 600 == 0.6 ms  -> 0'
        Delay(700);

        TIM4->CCR1 = 1500;      // 1500 == 1.5 ms -> 90'
        Delay(700);

        TIM4->CCR1 = 2100;      // 2100 == 2.1 ms -> 150'
        Delay(700);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Above is part of the code I'm currently working on. I'm getting a warning saying that 'Statement is unreachable' at the Return 0, and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Because the `return` is not reachable. The `while` loop never terminates. Really, not that difficult.

Comment: You should be grateful that you get a compiler error message that is actually meaningful and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete return 0; :) The compiler will notice that there is no way to reach end of main(), and it will not generate warning for reaching the end of int function without the return

Answer (score 4):

The while (1) loops forever, so without a way to get out if the loop, you won't get to the return.

To get rid of the warning, you can change main() to return void

void main (void)
{
}

Comment: `void main` is a non-standard C. It might be available as an extension though.

Comment: void main(void) is allowed since C99, and required for some microcontrollers.  However, may be compiler specific.  [See discussion about int main() vs void main()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356660/7928083)

Comment: Wrong!! The return value is needed in some toolchains (actually in the exit code) to determine how to end the program. main is not a part of compiler - it is just called by the startup code. C99 standard advices int return value - but it can be implementation defined as well.