# character array in bubble sort

Tags: c, string, char, bubble-sort

I have written the following code to get sorted strings in a 2-D character array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *,char *);

void main() {
    char a[20][20];
    int Pass = 0, i = 0, j = 0, n;

    printf("\nHow many elements you want to sort ? >> ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n\nEnter the elements to be sorted :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%s", a[i]);
    for (Pass = 1; Pass < n; Pass++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - Pass; j++)
            if (strcmp(a[j], a[j + 1]) < 0)
                swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
        printf("\n\nPass = %d\n", Pass);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf(" %s  ", a[i]);  
    }   
}

void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char *t;
    *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *t;
}
```

But, I get output as

```
How many elements you want to sort ? >> 5
Enter the elements to be sorted :
1 2 3 4 5
Pass = 1
2   3   4   5   1  
Pass = 2
3   4   5   2   1  
Pass = 3
4   5   3   2   1  
Pass = 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why do I encounter segmentation fault? (the same code works properly if I use an integer array instead of a character array)

Comment: main must return `int`

Comment: Your `swap` function is wrong. 1) `char *t;
    *t=*a;` : Using uninitialized variable. 2) What should be exchanged is an array rather than a pointer (or one `char`).

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings: `char *t;
    *t=*a;` should warn that `t` is used before initialization.

Comment: thanks @BLUEPIXY for pointing out, i assigned *t with memory by         't=(char*)malloc(20);' and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry point `main` *should* be defined as

```
int main()
```

or (with arguments)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

but may or may not return some value.

---

In function `swap` you are accessing uninitialized pointer which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There is no need to use pointer. Use plain `char`.

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char t;
    t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}
```

---

Also to avoid buffer overflow, you should tell `scanf()` how many characters to scan from input buffer

```
scanf("%19s",a[i]);
```

and check if scanning succeeded.

Now you should get correct results. **[Here is fixed code.](https://ideone.com/FxLgVu)**

Comment: C spec does not agree with your limited samples of acceptable `main()` signatures as other implementation defined, not UB, signatures are possible.

Comment: Thanks for info. Once somebody told me `void main` has UB and since that iam living in lie.

Comment: @FilipKočica most of the time `void main()` will work anyway. The problem here was obviously the uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @FilipKočica For some details: [int main() vs void main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up with your pointers in the `swap` method. Currently you're doing :

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char *t;
    *t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*t;
}
```

This line `*t = *a` seems to be a highly likely candidate for SEGV, since t is a character pointer which is uninitialized. I ran your code via gdb and gdb also said the same thing:

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/rohan/Documents/src/a.out 

How many elements you want to sort ? >> 5


Enter the elements to be sorted :
1 2 3 4 5

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554a21 in swap (a=0x7fffffffdce0 "1", b=0x7fffffffdcf4 "2") at testBubble.c:26
26      *t=*a;
(gdb)
```

You don't need t as a pointer variable. It's just a temporary variable needed for swapping. So change your method like this, which fixed the segmentation fault in my case:

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char t;
    t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The swap function is incorrect: you are dereferencing the uninitialized pointer `t`, causing undefined behavior: in your case a segmentation fault.

You should instead define `t` as a `char`:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

But this would only work for words with a single character.

To swap words of up to 19 bytes, use this:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char t[20];
    strcpy(t, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, t);
}
```

And add some extra tests and protections in the `main` function to avoid undefined behavior:

```
int main(void) {
    char a[20][20];
    int Pass = 0, i = 0, j = 0, n;

    printf("\nHow many elements you want to sort ? >> ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 20)
        return 1;
    printf("\n\nEnter the elements to be sorted :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%19s", a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (Pass = 1; Pass < n; Pass++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - Pass; j++) {
            if (strcmp(a[j], a[j + 1]) < 0)
                swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
        }
        printf("\nPass = %d\n", Pass);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf(" %s", a[i]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    return 0;  
}
```