# How do I filter out garbage from between 'Z' and 'a' in ASCII?

Tags: c, while-loop, ascii

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char ch;

    clrscr();
    ch = 'A';
    while(ch <= 'z')
    {
       printf("%c", ch);
       ch++;
    }
    getch();
 }
```

How do I remove garbage like `[`, `]`, `'`, `\`, etc. from the output of this program?

Comment: Please show you're code, otherwise we're just throwing guesses.

Comment: Can you bit a bit more specific? Also, can you show use some code that you've already tried? Stack Overflow is not a general-purpose code-writing service.

Comment: Read [ask], then edit your question to comply.  You will get better help that way.

Comment: Skip the stuff between `Z` and `a`. It's just basic ASCII.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca #include<studio.h>
void main()
{
char ch;
clrscr();
ch= 'A';
while(ch<= 'z')
{
printf("%c",ch);
ch++;
}
getch();
}

Comment: @user12153611 Put it in your question.

Comment: Also, please, if experienced users change your question's tags, there's a reason for that. Don't roll their changes back.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't forget to [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it properly.

Comment: And please [do not use `void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c).

Comment: @JL2210 Ok I will do that

Comment: And don't build/run the program anywhere that's not ASCII (notably, EBCDIC systems will produce no output).

Comment: What do you consider to be "garbage"?  Anything for which `isalpha()` returns false?  If so, that should be your clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in a comment skip everything between Z for example this way:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
    char ch = 'A';
    while(ch <= 'z'){
        if(ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 'a'){
            printf("%c", ch);
        } 
        ch++;
    } 
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively use a `for` loop since you know the beginning and end of the range of values:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
    char ch;
    for(ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){
        // loop through range of ASCII values from 'A' to 'z', upper case
        // and lower case letters, and print out only alphabetic characters.
        if(ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 'a'){
            // character is in range of 'A' thru 'Z' or 'a' thru 'z'.
            printf("%c", ch);
        } 
    } 
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively use the `isalpha()` function to detect if a character is alphabetic or not.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    char ch;
    // loop through range of ASCII values from 'A' to 'z', upper case
    // and lower case letters, and print out only alphabetic characters.
    for (ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)  isalpha (ch) && printf ("%c", ch);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```