# C using a string in shell command

Tags: c, linux, unix

Hello I'm trying to do this shell command "rm -rf test" by doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char name[] = "test";
char buffer[64];
int main()
{
        snprintf(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"rm -rf s% s%", name);
        system(buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

It will compile and run but doesn't remove the directory

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have %s repeated twice - should it just be `"rm -rf %s"`

Comment: What the hell is `s%`? I believe you meant `%s`.

Comment: Format modifiers are in the form of %s, not s%.

Comment: with "rm -rf %s" it still does not remove the test directory! but thank you for correcting me on that bit, there must be something else wrong too!

Comment: Works for me with `"rm -rf %s"`

Comment: You might try `"rm -rf ./%s"`.  Also, this question might be a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256945/1208914

Comment: It's working for me now too! not quite sure why id didn't a second ago! Thanks a lot for your help guys! :D

Comment: @stormCloud I looked at that and I couldn't get what I wanted from it this way I'll be able to input what I want

Comment: Very bad idea, and stormCloud's fix does not help. Consider what happens when the string name is `"test /"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `system` to run external processes, especially if the command line you're passing isn't constant. It will only make your life miserable. See `man fork` and `man exec` for the right way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char name[] = "test";
char buffer[64];

int main()
{
        snprintf(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"rm -rf %s", name);
        system(buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

it works for me.